# Need data from database for use in SpEL method level security

Tags: spring-security, spring-el

I would like to use SpEL to handle method level security. I run into an issue where the data passed to the method is not enough to determine if a user has access. Here is an example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.isAllowedAccessByCurrentUser(#.id)")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
    service.delete(id);
}
```

Here, the id variable is the ID of some object. To get the owner ID of the object (which is what i want to pass in the spel expression), I would need to do something like:

```
service.findOne(id).getUser().getId();
```

How can I get that ID and use it in the SpEL expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why need to so complicated?  You can simply create another method to specifically check if the current user can delete an object given that object Id and make the `@PreAuthorize` refer to this method:

```
@Service
public class SecurityService{

    @Autowired
    private Service service

    boolean isAllowToDeleteSomeObject(Long objectId){

       SomeObject anObject = service.findOne(objectId);

      //You should able to get the current user Id by SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). 
      //getCurrentUserId() simply encapsulate such codes for convenient.
       Long currentUserId = getCurrentUserId();

       if(anObject.getUser().getId().equals(currentUserId)){
         return true;
       }else{
         return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Then you can refer to this method in SpEL:

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.isAllowToDeleteSomeObject(#.id)")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {   
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but struggles to maintain modularity as the system grows. The reason why it was complicated because I have about 50 objects that get deleted in a similar, but non exact fashion. In the above solution, that would mean I have 50 autowired services. Would it be best practice to do those 50 autowires or somehow create an interface for each object that needs deletion and implement this method in the object itself?