# How to avoid null pointer exception using SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

I have the following statement:

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.isAllowedAccessByCurrentUser(@followingServiceImpl.findOne(#id).user.id)")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
```

The method specification takes in the ID of a following object that will get deleted if there is a following object with such an ID.

The PreAuthorize statement will work as long as findOne(#id) does not return null (returns not null if an object exists with that id).

The problem arises if the id passed in does not belong to a following object,which would mean that .user would result in a null pointer exception. What is the best way to pass the userId if exists (the following object exists) and if it doesnt exist, we can pass null to the isAllowedAccessByCurrentUser.

Currently as it is, we get null pointer exception if the Following Object with said ID does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) (i.e `?.`) to navigate the object structure. It will return null instead of throwing a `NullPointerException` when you access a property on a null :

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.isAllowedAccessByCurrentUser(@followingServiceImpl.findOne(#id)?.user?.id)")
```

But in this case, I will not put too much logic on SpEL. I will try to encapsulate all checking logic in one bean method .The SpEL in `@PreAuthorize` simply refer to this method similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956012/need-data-from-database-for-use-in-spel-method-level-security/56966666#56966666). It is much more easier to understand and normal java method call is much faster than the SpEL solution and is also type safety.